# Struggling with jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am creating a very simple register form with only two inputs and submit button.
The problem I am having is that it will only complete one if statement.

Here is the jQuery I made:

```
$("#usernameError").hide();
$("#passwordError").hide();

$("#registrationSubmit").click(function(){

  if($("#username").val() == ""){

    $("#usernameError").show();
    return false;
  }

  if($("#passwordReg").val() == ""){

    $("#passwordError").show();
    return false;
  }
});
```

And here is the HTML using bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-admin-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header admin">
         Please Enter Details
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body admin">
        <form id="registrationForm" action="registerAction.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Username</label>
            <input name="username" type="username" class="form-control" id="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
            <div id="usernameError" class="alert alert-danger pad" role="alert">A Username is required!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordReg" placeholder="Password">
            <div id="passwordError" class="alert alert-danger pad" role="alert">A Password is required!</div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="registrationSubmit" name="registrationSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Ok</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="validations.js"></script>
```

The script will validate the username and show the error, but doesn't do anything with the password.

Is it because I am using `return false` to prevent the form for submiting?
What can I use instead?

Comment: I don't get why you accepted the answer which suggests to remove the returns... This code works fine. There is no problem with the `return false;`. See this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vZPrjx?editors=1011) where I prevent the submit only because the demo is on Codepen. --- I would suggest an `else` part to those `if`, to remove the error messages... That is the only thing. --- In fact, removing the returns also removes the validation effect.. The form submits even if there is an empty field.

Comment: Submit your form with both inputs empty, it only comes up with username error, not both. The issue I was having was displaying both if they both needed to be displayed.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in your question about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how I've tagged it wrong. I've tagged it three different things 'jQuery', 'twitter bootstrap' and 'validation'. When you click on the validation tag it isn't exclusive to a jQuery validate plugin. So no where anywhere have I mentioned it is. Please let me know so I don't make the mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the reason, remove return statement. You can use a boolean variable errorOccurred and set it to true if there was an error. Somewhere you have a post function which will not post data if an error occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved it, returned false if errorOccured was set to true! First time I have used stack for a problem (only been coding a few weeks) and will do again! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning out of your code. Don't do that if you want to execute code after

```
var ValidationFailed = false;

if($("#username").val() == ""){

    $("#usernameError").show();
    ValidationFailed = true;
}

if($("#passwordReg").val() == ""){

    $("#passwordError").show();
    ValidationFailed = true;

}
//.....

return ValidationFailed;
```